# how can I have a non-responsive background?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, sass

I have two background images :

- image1 : the blue one (png file)
- image2 : the red one (png.file)

In the 1600px screen I want to have this :

[image]

In the 768px screen, I want to have this :

[image]

I have done the following code :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="container-full bg">
<div class="container">
   <div>My content....</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg {
 background-image: url(assets/images/bg-red.png), url(assets/images/bg-blue.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

but i don't get what i want as behavior, could you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: Your blue is a single color, so why use an image for that part?  You can just set background-color: #3F48CC; and then work with the red part from there.

Comment: @Sivak the red background is a radial-gradient, I just gave an example with red, it is not working with background-color, my problem is positionning

Comment: I see.  Rather than the same tag, how about having an extra tag in-between then to handle the parts separately?  Something like div class="bg1" for the blue and div class="bg2" for the red.

Comment: @Sivak I have obtain the same as picture one put when i resize screen i dont obtain what i want (see the picture two) :( by default backgrounds img is responsive, i dont want to have them responsive, do you understand what i mean ? look at the two pictures please

Answer (score 1):

inside bg class please handle background-image 560px as per your requirement

```css
.bg {
 background-image: url(assets/images/bg-red.png) 560px top, url(assets/images/bg-blue.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;}
```

```html
<div class="container-full bg">
<div class="container">
   <div>My content....</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I add this the two backgrounds disappear :(, I want that backgrounds must be not responsive but

Comment: both images disappear? or only one image disappear?